# In pandas, how to create a new column with a rank according to the mean values of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
+---------+-------+
| Country | value |
+---------+-------+
| UK      |    42 |
| US      |     9 |
| US      |    10 |
| France  |    15 |
| France  |    16 |
| Germany |    17 |
| Germany |    18 |
| Germany |    20 |
+---------+-------+
```

I want to create a new column that ranks each of the countries according to the mean of their values from largest to smallest

The output would look like the following

```
+---------+-------+---------+------+
| Country | value | Average | Rank |
+---------+-------+---------+------+
| UK      |    42 |      42 |    1 |
| US      |     9 |     9.5 |    4 |
| US      |    10 |     9.5 |    4 |
| France  |    15 |    15.5 |    3 |
| France  |    16 |    15.5 |    3 |
| Germany |    17 |      18 |    2 |
| Germany |    18 |      18 |    2 |
| Germany |    20 |      18 |    2 |
+---------+-------+---------+------+
```

Note that I don't need the average column, its just there to help with the explanation.

Many thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `mean` and then [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df['Average'] = df.groupby('Country')['value'].transform('mean')
df['Rank'] = df['Average'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
print (df)
   Country  value    Average  Rank
0       UK     42  42.000000   1.0
1       US      9   9.500000   4.0
2       US     10   9.500000   4.0
3   France     15  15.500000   3.0
4   France     16  15.500000   3.0
5  Germany     17  18.333333   2.0
6  Germany     18  18.333333   2.0
7  Germany     20  18.333333   2.0
```

Similar solution:

```
a = df.groupby('Country')['value'].transform('mean')
b = a.rank(method='dense', ascending=False)

df = df.assign(Average=a, Rank=b)
print (df)
   Country  value    Average  Rank
0       UK     42  42.000000   1.0
1       US      9   9.500000   4.0
2       US     10   9.500000   4.0
3   France     15  15.500000   3.0
4   France     16  15.500000   3.0
5  Germany     17  18.333333   2.0
6  Germany     18  18.333333   2.0
7  Germany     20  18.333333   2.0
```

Comment: Super clear and condensed. Don't see the point of similar solution though as same method is applied. Maybe your take is different +1

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**
I use a combination of `pd.DataFrame.join` and `pd.concat` after having `groupby` with `mean`

```
m = df.groupby('Country').value.mean()
df.join(
    pd.concat([m, m.rank(ascending=False)], axis=1, keys=['Average', 'Rank']),
    on='Country')

   Country  value    Average  Rank
0       UK     42  42.000000   1.0
1       US      9   9.500000   4.0
2       US     10   9.500000   4.0
3   France     15  15.500000   3.0
4   France     16  15.500000   3.0
5  Germany     17  18.333333   2.0
6  Germany     18  18.333333   2.0
7  Germany     20  18.333333   2.0
```

---

Similarly, with a double `join`

```
m = df.groupby('Country').value.mean()
df.join(m.rename('Avergage'), on='Country') \
  .join(m.rank(ascending=False).rename('Rank'), on='Country')

   Country  value    Average  Rank
0       UK     42  42.000000   1.0
1       US      9   9.500000   4.0
2       US     10   9.500000   4.0
3   France     15  15.500000   3.0
4   France     16  15.500000   3.0
5  Germany     17  18.333333   2.0
6  Germany     18  18.333333   2.0
7  Germany     20  18.333333   2.0
```

---

Or with `map` and `assign`

```
m = df.groupby('Country').value.mean()
df.assign(
    Average=df.Country.map(m),
    Rank=df.Country.map(m.rank(ascending=False))
)

   Country  value    Average  Rank
0       UK     42  42.000000   1.0
1       US      9   9.500000   4.0
2       US     10   9.500000   4.0
3   France     15  15.500000   3.0
4   France     16  15.500000   3.0
5  Germany     17  18.333333   2.0
6  Germany     18  18.333333   2.0
7  Germany     20  18.333333   2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use modern method-chaining approach to avoid mutating state and creating new variables:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Country': ['Russia', 'Russia', 'USA'], 'Value': [12, 15, 16]})

df.join(df.groupby('Country').
           mean().
           rank().
           rename(columns={'Value': 'Rank'}),
        on='Country')
```

Comment: Interesting but didn't work with two countries with same value.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I tried `{'Country': ['Russia', 'USA'], 'Value': [15, 15]}` and it gives `Rank: [1.5, 1.5]` which seems to be a correct answer.

Comment: Nvm, passing rank(method="dense") solved the "issue" I saw. (+1)

Comment: Yes, that's how rank is calculated by definition: if there's sevaral equal values, they share average of their possible ranks. In this case maximal rank is alwas equal to number of elements, that is good.

Comment: sorry I edited your post, was meant as a suggestion.